# Entity Framework Sum Method

Tags: entity-framework, sum, entity

```
        var resultList = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=. ; database=PersonnelTrackingSystem;Trusted_Connection=yes");
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT sum(takePay) FROM [PersonnelTrackingSystem].[dbo].[personnelSallaries] ", connection);
        da.Fill(resultList);
        return resultList;
```

This is my sql code for sum of the my integer take pay variables. How I can change them with entity framework ?
I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
 PersonnelTrackingSystemEntities entity = new PersonnelTrackingSystemEntities();
        return (entity.personnelSallaries.Sum(d => d.takePay)).ToString().ToList();
```

Comment: There should be just 1 scalar value result, so it should be just `entity.personnelSallaries.Sum(d => d.takePay)`. In your first code, that value is put into a `DataTable`. This table after filled will have just 1 cell (1 column x 1 row) containing the scalar value. Also the original code should use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScaler` instead because only 1 value is expected.

Comment: I understand. You are right. Thank you.